# How to simulate multiple POST and GET request sequentially in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

1. I need to send 1000 POST request. Each POST request would generate a unique ID along with other parameter.
2. Using that unique ID I need to send GET request for each and every unique ID.

I am new to Jmeter. Could someone please help how to do that in Jmeter. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll be using a HTTP Request element for the first call.

If you have the cURL equivalent for your request, you can use Tools => Import from cURL , this will create necessary element and configuration (ensure you use JMeter 5.3):

[image: curl Import]

You'll use an Extractor to extract the ID from the response based on type of response:

- JSON => [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- HTML => [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)
- XML => [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
- If none of above, you can use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) or [Regex Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

This will extract data in "id" variable

You can use it in Second HTTP Request as:

> ${id}